Building (CLEAN) Godot 3.2.3 for 32 bit windows raises bugs

area_bullet.cpp
C:\Users\Ren\Desktop\godot-3.2.3-stable\core/vector.h(66): error C2719: 'p_elem': formal parameter with requested alignment of 16 won't be aligned
c:\users\ren\desktop\godot-3.2.3-stable\modules\bullet\collision_object_bullet.h(222): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Vector<CollisionObjectBullet::ShapeWrapper>' being compiled
C:\Users\Ren\Desktop\godot-3.2.3-stable\core/vector.h(86): error C2719: 'p_val': formal parameter with requested alignment of 16 won't be aligned
scons: *** [modules\bullet\area_bullet.windows.opt.tools.32.obj] Error 2
scons: building terminated because of errors.

Upon reading further about this error, I think it's because somehow Vector works differently between 64 and 32 bit windows so I'd have to rewrite something there.
I tried copying from earlier build (3.0) that worked for me without a problem, but doesn't work. The only reason I need 3.2.3 or any later is because I need to be able to make projects for GLES2, and 3.0.0 doesn't support it.
